# Sampling from $d$ Gaussian distributions with ordered means - probability that minimum in a sample comes from the first distribution?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, normal-distribution

Suppose we sample from $d$ independent Gaussians with different means, denoted by $\mu_1, \mu_2, ... ,\mu_d$, such that the means are ordered such that $\mu_1 < \mu_2, ... <\mu_d$. All of the Gaussians have the same variance. What is the probability that the sample coming from the first Gaussian, $\mu_1$, is the minimum among the samples drawn from all $d$ Gaussians?

My approach was to find $P(X_1 < \min(X_2,X_3,...X_d))$. Let $X_m$ be this minimum. Its CDF is:

$F_{X_m}(z) = P(X_m < z) = 1 - P(X_m > z) $

$= 1 - \prod_{i = 2}^d P(X_i > z) = 1 - \prod_{i = 2}^d {(1 - F_{X_i}(z))}$

$ = 1 - \prod_{i = 2}^d {(1 - \Phi(\frac{z - \mu_i}{\sigma}))}$

Where $\Phi(x)$ is the CDF of a standard normal variable. Now I want to get $P(X_1 < X_m)$ from this expression somehow. Can you help me complete my approach?